# What is the current state of Botium

Tags: testing, chatbot, botium-box, conversational-ai

I'm currently working on a chatbot system for a larger energie company, and we are investigating a way to use more automatic testing.
For the website we are using Cypress, but we also want to test our WhatsApp integration and possibly IVR (voice). Therefore we are looking for alternative solutions.

I have read about a platform called Botium which might help us with building tests for this purpose, but all the manuals and documentation I have found so far are not providing me with how it should be implementated.
It looks like it was recently acquired by Cyara and all former links to [botium.ai](https://botium.ai) now points to its new product website by Cyara. The references to [Botium-Box](https://www.botiumbox.com) is broken and the [wiki](https://wiki.botiumbox.com) is also redirected.

Is the only product currently available the NPM-packages ([like described here](https://botium-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/01_quickstart/01_quickstart.html))?
And are the references to Botium-Box (like referenced in [this manual](https://support.botium.ai/hc/en-us/articles/7102678103311-E2E-Testing-with-Botium-and-Selenium-Appium) or [this tutorial](https://floriantreml.medium.com/tutorial-install-botium-box-on-aws-or-any-other-cloud-service-84bff33eaec7)) now obsolete?

I also found some [docker-images](https://hub.docker.com/u/botium) published by Botium. But without some proper documentation, I do not know which or how to use these.

I'm trying to get a grasp of what its current state is before I'm going to introduce this in our company. Is anyone familiar with its current state?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

They are probably redoing their documentation.

What I found on Google is the documentation page at the link:
https://botium-docs.readthedocs.io/

And their old forum:
https://forum.botium.ai/

Answer (score 0):

Botium is currently available as open source (https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-core/tree/master) and enterprise edition (reach out to Cyara throug hthe chatbot widget on https://cyara.com/)